# Mapping Another key as foreign key instead of primary key in sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring mvc with hibernate and i have a lookup table in my SQL server database. this table has 4 columns

```
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "VLE_LOOKUP_DATA")

         public class Lookup_Data{

           @Id
           @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
           private long ID;

           @Column(name = "ENTITYNAME")
           private String ENTITYNAME;

           @Column(name = "CODE")
           private String CODE;

           @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
           private String DESCRIPTION;
       }
```

This table has one to one relationship with multiple tables for example with student table.

```
    @Entity
  @Table(name = "STUDENT")

     public class student{

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private long STUDENT_ID;

       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
       private Lookup_Data DEPARTMENT_ID;

       @Column(name = "Name")
       private String Name;

       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "GENDER_ID")
       private Lookup_Data GENDER_ID;
   }
```

Here the foreign key came from Lookup Table is not the Primary key(ID) of Lookup data.its column name **CODE** which is referenced as foreign key in other tables.That is why when i run this example the OneToOne relation gives error as

```
   java.sql.SQLException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar to data type int.
```

because code is string value.

Is there any way to implement this scenario in **Spring Mvc boot application**?

**Note:**    In **sql server** this query can do desired work.

```
  SELECT * FROM STUDENT as e  left join VLE_LOOKUP_DATA as di on e.DEPARTMENT_ID=di.CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA is designed to support wide range of DBMS ( database server ) so it just support SQL standard specification.

In your current case, compare equals between 2 fields is not supported by SQL spec ( may be just supported by sql server only ) so JPA raise this error. So I think instead of using relational mapping, to get the Lookup_data you can do normal JPQL or native query.

Comment: native query is working but in case of normal pk's mapping we do not need to use join query.it populated automatically with fk.so can we get this in current case

Comment: Any case, do mapping between different data type is not supported.

Comment: different data type means other than int type? like in this case its string type. DEPARTMENT_ID(string)-->CODE(string) as we cannot specify here that which table column is referenced as foreign key here.

Comment: Okay. If that the solution should be
 @OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", referencedColumnName="CODE")

Comment: its not working in my case giving error of serializable.is there any special configurations to be done/

Comment: You entity should implement java.io.serializable